# Migrate data from one database to another in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two databases Test and Live. I want to push all the data from Live database to Test database. Also , i want to compare the schema/structure of both databases before data migration , in order to know if there is any schema/structure change. 
The Test Database contains old data , i want to replace it with the fresh data from Live. 
What is the best approach to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Backup and restore.  Restore the Live database from the Test backup using the overwrite option.  You can restore to a different name and different files.

Comment: is it possible to restore to same test db name ? will it create problems?

Comment: Yes you can restore to the same name

Answer (score 0):

```
1.If you are using Visual Studio 2012 then do the Schema Compare for Both Test and Production Environment .make sure that both environments 
datatypes and Key Constraints Remain the Same.Then do the Generate Scripts of Production Database and execute it on Test new database 
2. Now Just take the Shrink backup or Compressed Mode back up of your Production Environment.
3.Now in the Test Environment Create New Database or Replicate of your Existing Database 
Right Click on new Database -> Genrate Script option 
4.Then Execute the Database script with new file groups 
5.Now Restore the Production backUp on Test BackUp with click overwrite
```

Comment: Why would you need to 1-4?  The restore does all that.